# Simplify dict to list with if function

Tags: python

Can this function be written in a more Pythonic shorter way?

```
def getExtra(d):
    l = list()
    for x in list(d.items()):
        if x.startswith('extra'):
        l.append(x)
    return l
```

Comment: A start to make it more Pythonic would be to use snake_case instead of camelCase (`get_extra`).

Comment: A good start would be to make it acutally run without throwing an exception. `x`, being a part of `d.items()`, is a tuple of key and value; tuples don't have a `startswith` method, which leads to an AttributeError. You probably want to call `startswith` on the key or the value, thus `x[0]` or `x[1]`, not on `x`. Furthermore, it makes no sense to call `list(d.items())` as long as you just iterate over the dict and don't want to change its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's why [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is there:

```
[x for x in d if x.startswith('extra')]
# iterate on keys, or you can modify it to iterate on values
```

Are you sure you want `list(d.items())` there? Your code doesn't work as `list(d.items())` returns a *tuple*, which doesn't have `startswith` function.

Comment: No matter what OP wants, I'm sure the `list` call is completely superfluous. Also, this code, just like OPs, throws an AttributeError on `x.startswith` as `x` is a tuple, not a string.

Comment: @l4mpi You're right, I was only referring syntax as a black box. Edited accordingly.